# Apache Rewrite URL Creating Linking Issues

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

**Problem:** rewrite url causing some links to break.

**.htaccess has below rule:**

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/[-0-9a-zA-Z]+$ index.php?action=blog&postID=$1\%23disqus_thread [NC]

**Style sheet reference in header template:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

I can click on:

domain.com/blog/1/title-of-article and get to the file just fine, but style sheet link breaks

If I go directly to:

domain.com/index.php?action=blog&postID=1#.UYV1mcqRiSo then the style sheet loads fine *(ignore #.UYV1mcqRiSo, that is code from Disqus)*.

This is also breaking my logo link, which is:

```
<a href="./">
```

Instead of taking me to domain.com, it's going to domain.com/blog/1/

**My basic file structure is:**

index.php and style.css is in root, which loads up viewPost.php in/templates folder.

What is going and how do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution: Just set your links relative to the domain root, by fronting them with a slash (resp. removing the dot referring to the current folder in the link):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
<a href="/">Logo</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I picked you answer because it fixed my issue. I do have an additional question... Now that I changed my paths from "./" to "/" links are working fine on my website, however on localhost (on my box) its all off now. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well, that’s probably because on your localhost you don’t have this site in the root folder? You could either write the path dynamically with PHP, according to a config variable – or, and this is what I’d recommend, you could set up a separate VirtualHost pointing at the folder your project resides in and a fake local domain name (`hosts` file under Windows) so that this project _can_ be accessed directly under the domain root. (Setting up your dev environment to mimic your live environment as closely as possible is a good idea in general.)

Comment: Ahh rookie mistake. Had the path in my httpd.conf file off. Definitely going to get development and production boxes matching. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

**1. About the stylesheet link**

You have to include these conditions in your .htaccess before the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The first means that rewrite rules work only if the requested URL is **not** to an existing file, and the second does the same for existing directories. Without these conditions the request for `style.css` is also passed to your `index.php` file, not to the `style.css` file directly.

If you have these rules already and it still doesn't work then the problem is with URL paths, see below.

**2. About URL paths**

You're using relative URLs in your links, both in the `<a href="./">` and in the `<link>` tag. In this case they are resolved to the current directory of the URL (it doesn't matter that it's rewritten to the same file serverside, the path is prepared on the client side and every part separated with a slash `/` is treated as a directory. Thus if the current URL is *domain.com/blog/1/*, `./` is resolved to *domain.com/blog/1/*.) The path to `style.css` may be resolved to *domain.com/blog/1/style.css*. If you want these links work as if they're directly after the domain name in the URL, you have to use absolute URLs, i.e., `/` without the dot for the link on your logo; `/style.css` for the stylesheet link.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although I picked another answer, I did learn from your thoughtful answers and explanations.