# URL rewriting breaks relative references to files

Tags: html, apache, url-rewriting, relative-path

I have an HTML page, for example `www.somesite.com/Directory/foo.html`. On this page, I reference a style sheet and an image which are currently located in the root directory. I'm referencing the files relatively like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../foos_style.css">
<img src="../foos_image.png" alt="" />
```

I have set up Apache 2.4.4 rewrite_mode to redirect `www.somesite.com/Directory/foo.html` to `www.somesite.com/foo/gets/redirected/to/thispage.html`. I managed to successfully rewrite the URL, but now neither the style sheet nor the image gets loaded. Apparently, it has something to do with relative linking.

Is there any way that I can fix this issue, so that the image and the style sheet get loaded relative to the original URL and not the rewritten one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Rewrite URL Creating Linking Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378984/apache-rewrite-url-creating-linking-issues)

Comment: Relative URLs are converted to absolute by the client, not the server. The client doesn't know about rewriting on the server, it bases the conversion on the URL that it's using for the page.

Comment: What is the real location of the CSS and image files?

Comment: if you need to reference the root, do you need to use relative files? Can you do something like `<img src="/foos_image.png" />`?

Comment: on the root direcory , but since the URL rewriting is the last thing I'm doing before the sites Deployment I would rather not to mess with my mark up , IS there any way to overcome this problem ?